# Jinja2 template not rendering if-elif-else statement properly

Tags: python, css, if-statement, jinja2

I am trying to set the text color using css in a jinja2 template.  In the following code  I want to set the output string to print in a specific font color if the variable contains a string.  Everytime the template is generated though it prints in red due to the else statement, it never see the first two conditions even though the output should be matched, I can tell what the output from the variable is when the table generates and it is as expected.  I know my css is correct due to the printing of the string in red by default.

My first thought was to enclose the string I was checking for in quotes but that didn't work.  Next was that jinja was not expanding `RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)]` but the for loop above it works, `RepoName` is expanded upon properly.  I know if I add the braces it will print the variable which I am fairly certain will either break the template or just not work.

I tried looking at these sites and went through the list of global expressions as well but couldn't find any examples similar to mine or a direction in which to look further.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#if

http://wsgiarea.pocoo.org/jinja/docs/conditions.html

```
   {% for repo in RepoName %}
       <tr>
          <td> <a href="http://mongit201.be.monster.com/icinga/{{ repo }}">{{ repo }}</a> </td>
       {% if error in RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] %}
          <td id=error> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td> <!-- I want this in green if it is up-to-date, otherwise I want it in red -->
       {% elif Already in RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] %}
          <td id=good> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td>   <!-- I want this in green if it is up-to-date, otherwise I want it in red -->
       {% else %}
            <td id=error> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td> <!-- I want this in green if it is up-to-date, otherwise I want it in red -->
       </tr>

       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You are testing if the values of the *variables* `error` and `Already` are present in `RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)]`. If these variables don't exist then an [undefined object](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#variables) is used.

Both of your `if` and `elif` tests therefore are false; there is no undefined object in the value of RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)].

I think you wanted to test if certain *strings* are in the value instead:

```
{% if "error" in RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] %}
    <td id="error"> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td>
{% elif "Already" in RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] %}
    <td id="good"> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td>
{% else %}
    <td id="error"> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td>
{% endif %}
</tr>
```

Other corrections I made:

- Used `{% elif ... %}` instead of `{$ elif ... %}`.
- moved the `</tr>` tag out of the `if` conditional structure, it needs to be there always.
- put quotes around the `id` attribute

Note that most likely you want to use a *`class`* attribute instead here, not an `id`, the latter must have a value that must be unique across your HTML document.

Personally, I'd set the class value here and reduce the duplication a little:

```
{% if "Already" in RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] %}
    {% set row_class = "good" %}
{% else %}
    {% set row_class = "error" %}
{% endif %}
<td class="{{ row_class }}"> {{ RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] }} </td>
```

Comment: {% set row_class = "good"  if "Already" in RepoOutput[RepoName.index(repo)] else  "error" %} should work too.