# Display different <div> depending on arrays length

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, jinja2, lektor

I'm on my first JinJa2 project.
I want to display cars. A car can have one or more options.
If a car has one option, show that. If it has more, hide it for the moment.
Here's my code:

```
//...
{% set products = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche'] %}
{% set options = ['Small', 'Sport', 'Coupe', 'Jeep'] %}

{% for product in products %}
    {% include '../car-product-item.html' with context %}
{% endfor %}

{% if options|length > 1 %}
    //If a car has more options, hide this options for the moment
    <div class="order-more-options" style="display: none; background: green">
        {% for product in options %}
        {% include '../car-product-item.html' with context %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% elif  options|length == 1 %}
    //If a car has one option, show this option
    <div class="order-more-options" style="display: block; background: orange">
        {% for product in options %}
        {% include '../car-product-item.html' with context %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
//...
```

For some reason its not working. The options are always hidden.
What am I doing wrong?

I checked a [Tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/), the [Docu](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/) and another [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024661/jinja2-template-not-rendering-if-elif-else-statement-properly) but nothing helped.

Comment: Looks fine for me, you should print, the options/product to make sure it is not empty(if the real case is more complicated). Also check if the `include` adds your code outside of the loop/if to make sure it is not empty.

Comment: There are items in the array, I checked it

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine, when I skip the

```
{% include ...
```

commands using the following code:

```
{% set products = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche'] %}
{% set options = ['Small', 'Sport', 'Coupe', 'Jeep'] %}

{% if options|length > 1 %}
    <div>more than one options</div>
    <div class="order-more-options" style="display: none; background: green">
        {% for product in options %}
        {{product}}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% elif  options|length == 1 %}
    <div>exactly one option</div>
    <div class="order-more-options" style="display: block; background: orange">
        {% for product in options %}
        {{product}}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Do you use the correct path to *car-product-item.html*? Try to put the file *car-product-item.html* to the templates folder and change your include-lines to {% include '/car-product-item.html' ...%}.