# flask template rendering weird

Tags: python, flask, post

Looking at this, it should work right?

It seems like the get request is overwriting the post request return because it only renders no error.

Why is that?

---

index.html

```
{% if error %}
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>no error</p>
{% endif %}
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if post_data['message'] == False:
            return render_template('index.html', error='not detected')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

edit:
still haven't found out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at `post_data['message']`. Are you absolutely sure it's `False`? If it's the string 'False', the code falls through and won't render an error.

Comment: ya i'm posting:
```body: JSON.stringify({'message': false})```.
tried it with False as well, which gives ```Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `else` or `elif`.

`else`:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if post_data['message'] == False:
            return render_template('index.html', error='not detected')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

`elif` (recommended):

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if post_data['message'] == False:
            return render_template('index.html', error='not detected')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: still only shows no error

Comment: @hwhat aha I see the issue. There is no error passed in to `render_template` when a GET request is sent. You only do so when sending a POST request.

Comment: doesn't work even with ```('index.html', error=xxx)``` in the get request

Comment: @hwat try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024797/20616402

Comment: not sure what to change from that

Comment: I haven't worked in Jinja in a while so I don't know what the problem is.